# 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, while running using nodemon nameoffile.js

Tags: express, nodemon

I am currenlty learning express.js for that purpose i have installed express and nodemon globally so whenever i want to run command nodemon express1.js getting error ,even i have installed this globally and also save express dependencies in package.json file.

installation i did like this

```
for express  npm install --save express
 for nodemon  npm install -g nodemon
```

previoulsy this way installed (npm insatll --save nodemon)

still getting error like this

'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in cmd type

```
npm config get prefix
```

and hit enter it will show the npm path that path we need to copy  and go to mycomputer or in windows10 'This pc' right click on This pc select  on properties then ->on left side click on advanced system setting now system properties pop up will open in that select advanced tab and click environment variables and select path from list click on edit and paste that path which is copied but make sure that if any other path is already present use semicolon to end of that path  then  paste this new path and save . but sometimes if it didn't work then restart your computer because sometimes environment varaible changes will not take effect so restart your system after completing this procedure

Comment: In my case, the path points to C:\Users\djob\AppData\Roaming\npm which is empty

Answer (score 1):

In your console try `nodemon --version` if it returns a version then it means nodemon is installed otherwise there might be an error while installing nodemon
installing with this command it will install it in your project folder.

npm install --save-dev nodemon

Comment: again getting same error nodemon is not recognized as internal or external but while installtion is done successfully

Comment: npm insatll --save nodemon
install with this command and check it appears in your package.json file

Comment: @Danial, there is a typo error in the command you have given; "insatll".          The command should be: `npm install --save nodemon`